# Странная работа задержки TimeUnit

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Нужно чтобы сразу после нажатия появился текст, а через секунду продолжилось бы выполнение. На деле выходит все не так - задержка срабатывает раньше появление надписи.

```java
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case 1:
            tvOutAns.setTextColor(colorGreen);
            tvOutAns.setText("правильно: " + answer);
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            createTask();
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: а вы поставьте 10000 и проверьте, кажется вам или все же нет

Comment: Проверил текст появляется через десять секунд.

Comment: TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(x) вызывает Thread.sleep, т.е. "замораживает" тред. Соответственно вы дали команду установить новый текст, оно там начало ворочать гуём, а тут вы ему НА! Стоять бояться!

Comment: Спасибо. Понятно. А что же делать?

Comment: Запустить ему цикл на подольше и задержку туда воткнуть? Но это как-то негуманно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так можно

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     // код, который надо запустить через секунду
    }
}, 1000);
```

Или в модных лямбдах (рекомендую кстати, гуглите retrolambda)

```
(new Handler()).postDelayed(()->{/*код*/},1000);
```

Comment: Спасибо! И за объяснение и за совет!